# Set component property to data from store

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-components

Seems it's a bad practice to retrieve data from your component, but this is kind of an experiment (hope the code explains itself)

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    store: Ember.inject.service(),
    items: [],
    init () {
        this._super(...arguments);
        var store = this.get('store'); 
        let items =  store.findAll('dealtype');
    }
});
```

While I can see my api is being hit (debug) and data returned (ember inspector) when looping over "items" in my component template, it's always empty.

Curious what I'm doing wrong (learning still)

Comment: `items` is a promise, which is probably not what you want. Did you mean to say `store.findAll('dealtype').then(items => this.set('items', items))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't set `items` in your `init`
Set that like :

`...
let items =  store.findAll('dealtype');
this.set('items', items);`

Comment: This will set the `items` property to a promise, which probably won't work well.

Comment: @torazaburo no, it doesn't matter. That is not a normal promise. It is array proxy too

Comment: Remember Ember Component EXTENDS an Ember object. So you have to use this.get and this.set to access the properties, which is why this works and 'let = ' does not.